# Songs to play with notes of a major seventh

Tags: keyboard

My son just got a litle fischer price four note "piano". The notes are F, A, C, and E, I think. At any rate they seem to pair as consecutive thirds: Major, minor, Major; forming a Major 7th all together.

Can anyone suggest relatively simple songs I can play with these four notes?

Comment: The first half of *One Note Samba*.

Comment: I suggest more ambition -- give your son a grand piano, regardless of his age!

Comment: If you can't manage a grand, at least get him an instrument with an octave. In 5 minutes he's going to be asking "Dad, where are the missing notes?"

Comment: Nobody has asked how old he is.  If he's, say, two, then wait a bit.

Comment: Well hes 8 months, actually. He mostly just flips it over and bangs on the bottom. But the songs are for me to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F and A make up two thirds of an F chord. C and E make up two thirds of a C chord. Several songs use only two chords, for example, Dance the night away, Jambalaya. They can be accompanied using the diads, like a chord on each beat of the 4/4 bar, changing where appropriate.